# Origin of "and so it goes" quote in science fiction

Tags: quotes

Most online searches for the phrase "and so it goes" lead to Slaughterhouse Five by Kurt Vonnegut published in 1969.

However it is used a few times in 'Repent Harlequin said the Tick-tock man' by Harlan Ellison and that was published in 1965.

My question is simply:-
Which sci fi writer is the one who came up with the phrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression, "So it goes," was a standard one well before the 1960s dates of either of the science fiction works you mention.  Although Google Ngrams results must be taken with a grain of salt (the makeup of the corpus is not consistent over time, and many scanned documents are misdated), [a simple search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so%20it%20goes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cso%20it%20goes%3B%2Cc0) indicates that the popularity of "so it goes" may have peaked in the 1940s.

Ellison's usage just seems to be everyday use of a normal idiomatic expression.  On the other hand, Vonnegut uses, "So it goes," as repeated motif in *Slaughterhouse Five*; the quote is repeated after each death that occurs in the story.  So, to the extent that the phrase is widely recognized in science fiction, that is probably Vonnegut's influence.